# Firefox Aurora failed to launch

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I have installed Firefox Aurora channel. After updating it will no longer start - Task Manager shows Firefox is running but I don't see any window.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Simon: Windows 7

Comment: Silly question, didn't notice. Just started in the safe mode. Applied update again. Everything is ok. Should have tried it before.